# ArgumentNullException when calling Upgrade() on application settings

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, application-settings

I have a windows service that uses user scope settings and loads them during service start using following code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
if (Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
  Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
  Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
}
```

On one production machine the service cannot be started and I am getting an `ArgumentNullException` from the `Reload()` method with following stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
  at System.IO.Directory.GetParent(String path)
  at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPreviousConfigFileName(Boolean isRoaming)
  at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.Upgrade(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties, Boolean isRoaming)
  at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.Upgrade(SettingsContext context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
  at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade()
```

It is not documented that `Upgrade()` method could throw the `ArgumentNullException`. Does anyone have an idea what could this mean and / or how could I solve it without rebuilding of the service?

Comment: What kind of application is it? I have only used this with a click once deployed windows forms app and it's worked great for me.

Comment: you got this exceptions from log file or event viewer?

Comment: @RossDargan it is a windows service, installed using msi created by standard setup project from VS2008

Comment: @DJ, I got this caught in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event handler and logged to the windows event log.

Comment: looks like it is trying to access a config file which is not there.

Comment: I can't say that for sure, but it is very probable that the file is not there (because it is a fresh installation). But it works on dozens maybe hundreds other computers.

Comment: have you tried to run as admin? Means you can try by running the service as admin if not done till now.

Comment: What user is the service running as?

Comment: Logged user is administrator on the local computer but as a service is it is running under local system account (also when no user is logged), so it should not have any influence.

Comment: I'm seeing this exception as well on Upgrade() of settings of our WPF application. No rhyme or reason but around 1% of our user base sees this problem.